# Angular 6 Fallback/Redirect if param is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'd like to have routes set like this:

Base Route: `/events/:date`

A click event redirects to `/events`, then the routes file would have to fallback to `/events/moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` to render `EventsComponent`.

Inside `EventsComponent` you have an action to change date, which navigates according to the day you selected, in this case the routes file wouldn't need to fallback, since the `:date` is defined.

I just don't know how to apply it to my needs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to avoid navigation when the date parameter is not defined then you should have 2 routes and add a canActivate guard to the second:

```
{
   path: 'events',
   component: EventsComponent
},
{
   path: 'events/:date',
   component: EventsDetailComponent,
   canActivate: EventDefinedGuard
}
```

where `EventDefinedGuard` is a [router guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) that check for the param to be defined, otherwise redirects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but maybe I wasn't that clear. I need to force a redirect to add a `:date`, if it's not defined, to render `EventsComponent`, but if it is defined I just need to render `EventsComponent`. I need that cause the part of my app that redirects to `events` cannot be changed right now to force a "first value" of `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')`. I can only change the action part inside `EventsComponent` to change the date selected.

Comment: Ok so you have only one route and need to make sure there's always a parameter when going to `/events/:date`. You might try to add a canActivate route on a top route (base route maybe) where you inspect the destination url and eventually check the event parameter, if that's undefined you can just redirect setting a parameter.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer with updated code so I can accept it?